# What is the convention to document types used in Lua?

Tags: lua, conventions, typing

I come from the strongly typed world and I want to write some Lua code. How should I document what type things are? What do Lua natives do? [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)? Something else?

For example:

```
local insert = function(what, where, offset)
```

It's impossible to tell at a glance whether we're talking about strings or tables here.

Should I do

```
local sInsert = function(sWhat, sWhere, nOffset)
```

or

```
-- string what, string where, number offset, return string
local insert = function(what, where, offset)
```

or something else?

What about local variables? What about table entries (e.g. `someThing.someProperty`)?

Comment: Code style is usually dictated by your employer.

Comment: Document the source in the manner that your IDE supports for its content assistance and popover help.

Comment: Complicating the issue is that parameters are often polymorphic. A table key can be any type except `nil`. A table value can be any type.  Some functions support tables or functions for certain parameters.... Your `where` is a potential case.

Comment: I've seen several times Haskell-style annotations (sort-of): `insert :: string -> number -> string`, etc.

Comment: There's a strong belief in "duck typing" among many Lua users. For example, if `what` needs to be a string, a table or userdata with an appropriate `_tostring()` metamethod associated is often just as acceptable. Being over-specific about type runs counter to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reference on thoughts and opinions on Lua style in the community (or a particular community?), read this: [LuaStyleGuide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide).

The closest one could get to an enforced style would be the format used by [LuaDoc](https://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/index.html), as it's a fairly popular documentation generator used by high profile projects such as LuaFileSystem.

Answer (score 1):

There are only seven types in Lua.

Here are some conventions (some of them might sound a bit obvious; sorry):

- Anything that sounds like a string, should be a string: `street_address`, `request_method`. If you are not sure you can add `_name` (or any other suffix that makes clear it's a substantive) to it: `method_name`
- Anything that sounds like a number, should be a number: `mass`, `temperature`, `percentage`. When in doubt, add `number`, `amount`, `coefficient`, or whatever fits : `number_of_children`, `user_id`. The names `n` and `i` are usually given to numbers. If a number must be positive or natural, make assertions at the top of the function.
- Boolean parameters are either an adjective (`cold`, `dirty`) or `is_<adjective>` (`is_wet`, `is_ready`).
- Anything that sounds like a verb should be a function: `consume`, `check`. You can add `_function`, `_callback` or `_f` if you need to clarify it further: `update_function`, `post_callback`. The single letter `f` represents a function quite often. And usually you should only have one parameter of type function (recommended to put it at the end)
- Anything that sounds like a collection should be a table: `children`, `words`, `dictionary`. People typically don't differentiate between array-like tables and dictionary-like tables, since both can be parsed with `pairs`. If you need to specify that a table is an array, you could add `_array` or `_sequence` at the end of the name. The letter `t` typically means table.
- Coroutines are not used quite often; you can follow the same rules as with functions, and you can also add `_cor` to their names.
- Any value can be `nil`.

  - If it's an optional value, initialize it at the top of the function: `options = options or {}`
  - If it's a mandatory value, make an assertion (or return error): `assert(name, "The name is mandatory")`